# How does Django build URLs that depend on a site?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-cms, django-sites

I am trying to find out how does Django build URLs, especially those that depend on multiple sites. Where does Django build URLs and how is the site domain prepended to the user defined URL patterns?

Basically, I have several Django CMS pages and multiple Django sites. I need to know how are the URLs created for a page that relies on a different site than the current site; namely, how is the correct site's domain added to a page's URL.

Comment: The site domain is not prepended by Django. Django just handles the part after the domain.

Comment: And if I have multiple sites (Django sites, that is), how are the URLs properly constructed?

Comment: Multiple sites? you mean multiple apps?

Comment: I guess he means multiple projects.

Comment: No, no. I am talking about multiple sites using the contrib module, `sites`. Basically I use Django CMS and have multiple pages created on several sites. I need to know how is the correct site added to a page's URL.

Comment: @AndreiHorak it isn't. The sites app has nothing to do with the URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, the I might have misunderstood some things. Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like, adding a Django site's domain to the URL has to be done manually. From [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#getting-the-current-domain-for-full-urls):

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=3)
>>> obj.get_absolute_url()
'/mymodel/objects/3/'
>>> Site.objects.get_current().domain
'example.com'
>>> 'http://%s%s' % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, obj.get_absolute_url())
'http://example.com/mymodel/objects/3/'
```